# JNI Casting jobject from one class to another

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So if I had a `jobject` from jclass `clazz1` and I wanted to type cast it to jclass `clazz2`. How would would go about doing that?

I check [Oracle JNI docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656) and the only reference to casting is from the function `IsAssignableFrom()` but not much more.

Comment: There should be no need to cast any Java objects on the C++ side. Making sure that `clazz1` actually can be used as a `clazz2` by calling `IsAssignableFrom` seems like a good idea. Assuming that that is the case, you should be able to use your `jobject` as if it were a `clazz2`.

Comment: You are right. I completely overthought that.

Feel free to put the answer, @Michael, and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `jobject` represents a reference to some Java object, but the Java type of that object is not important. You can always assign one `jobject` to another `jobject`.

However, the Java type *does matter* once you try to actually use the object for anything, like calling one of its methods or accessing one of its fields.

At that point you should ensure that the object you're providing meets the following requirements:

- The object's class is exactly the same as the expected class, OR
- The object's class is a subclass of the expected class, OR
- The object's class implements the expected class' interface.

That's precisely what `IsAssignableFrom` will tell you.

If your `clazz1` object meets these requirements you can use it in your C++ code as if it were a `clazz2`.